# How can I solve the integral below?

Tags: indefinite-integrals

How can I solve this? I've tried many ways, but it's all useless. Need help!

$$\int\frac{\mathrm dx}{a^2\sin^2x-b^2\cos^2x}$$

Comment: i would use the Weierstrass substitution

Comment: $\int{\sec^{2}\left(x\right) \over a^{2}\tan^{2}\left(x\right) - b^{2}}\,\mathrm{d}x$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:

Divide numerator & denominator by $\cos^2x$

Set $\tan x=u$

OR

Divide numerator & denominator by $\sin^2x$

Set $\cot x=v$

Comment: Damn, it's pretty obvious! Thanks a lot, man!